# Progress is never equal ProgressEnd JSSOR Plugin

Tags: jquery, jssor

Using jssor plugin as follows :

```
function initJssorSlide() {
    var jssor_sliderh=[];
    var isPlaying = true;
    $.each(["sliderh1_container", "sliderh2_container"], function(index, value) {

        var sliderhOptions = {
            $AutoPlay: true, //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $PauseOnHover: 1, //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1, //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
            $SlideDuration: 1000, //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $SlideWidth: 89, //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            $SlideHeight: 90, //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 3, //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $Cols: 8, //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $Align: 0, //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 0, //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20, //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            $DragOrientation: 1,
            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {//[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$, //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2, //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $Steps: 1, //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                $Rows: 1, //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 0, //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 0, //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            }
        };
        jssor_sliderh[index] = new $JssorSlider$(value, sliderhOptions);

        console.log(index);
        if (index === 1) { // if second slider since I have to Horzontial sliders with reverse motion
            jssor_sliderh[index].$Pause();
            jssor_sliderh[index].$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_STATE_CHANGE, function(slideIndex, progress, progressBegin, idleBegin, idleEnd, progressEnd)
            {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    if (progress === progressEnd) {
                        jssor_sliderh[index].$PlayTo(slideIndex - 1);
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#sliderh2_container").hover(function() {
                isPlaying = false;
            }, function() {
                isPlaying = true;
                jssor_sliderh[index].$Prev();
            });

            }
        else if (index === 0){
            $("#sliderh1_container").mouseleave(function() {
                jssor_sliderh[0].$Next();
            });
        }
    });
```

After being working suddenly `EVT_STATE_CHANGE` are entered once and progress is not equal progressEnd by any mean tried using `EVT_PROGRESS_CHANGE` and it worked but with over 180 calls the performance would be so bad so why `EVT_STATE_CHANGE` is entered once and how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check out the demo http://www.jssor.com/testcase/event-handling-state-change.source.html

Maybe you missed the latest updates, or I forgot to update you.

Comment: No you did, My mistake sorry for that